# LAN FIle and/or Service Search

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scripting, ntfs, search

Anyone know of a tool/script that I can use to find if a single file is present on machines on my LAN?

The file would be in the same place every time.

Same applies to a service. Need to know which servers have a particular service running or not on the LAN.

It's a lot of servers to audit, so looking for a way to save time rather than jumping into each one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use LAN Search Pro. It works well and it's free.

http://www.softperfect.com/products/lspro